# Is sample method of random library unique when seeded with unique number?

Tags: python, unique, random

I have code block below that should generate random **unique** strings. Is usage of sample method of random safe enought to do this?

```
def generate_voucher_code_string(length=13):
    rand = random.Random()
    rand.seed(get_seq(VOUCHER_CODE_SEQ_KEY))
    return ''.join(rand.sample(VOUCHER_CODE_CHARS, length))
```

Note: get_seq method returns a different number every time it called.

Answer (score 2):

No the random module may produce the same output for different seeds. The probability of that depends on the algorithm used.

What you probably want is the `uuid` module which produces [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) universally unique identifiers based on hashes. The hashes are usually so large that the probability of non-uniqueness is negligible.

Comment: "No the random module may produce the same output for different seeds." Can you show evidence about it? I've searched documentation found nothing about this.

Comment: its not documented because uniqueness of the first few samples depending on the seed is not a property that classifies prngs. python uses a 32 bit mersenne twister which has a huge state space so it is likely that the initial output is unique for its seed, but it the random module is still not designed for this purpose. The uuid module is.